# mod_rewrite several conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not an expert with working with mod_rewrite and I would like to ask if these rules are properly constructed?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(pl|en)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

I was just about to the last rule add a rule that will open a page with www.

I do not really know if it is made correctly (of course, everything works fine, but wanting to make sure that does not commit any error).

Peter.

Comment: The first condition- and rule-set states that `www.` should be prepended to the host-name if not present. This is correct. The second rule, naturally not tied to the condition, rewrites `{lang}/{segment}.html` to `index.php` with the relevant query parameters. If this is what you intended, then your code is correct. (Note: I have added this as a comment as I believe the question to be too broad for Stack Overflow, but I do feel the need to let you know that it is correct.)

Comment: **Side tip:** If you would like to make your `www.` redirect HTTPS-agnostic, then use [this condition- and rule-set](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-www-in-a-generic-way).

Comment: @MikeRockett Thank you for your answer. Yes, I just wanted to site opened with the WWW and rewrited conditions from the last rule.